# Macro for drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SolverMacro()
'
' SolverMacro Macro
'

'
    Range("F29").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$F$29", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$18:$D$26", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$F$29", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$18:$D$26", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12

    If (Range("f29").Value > Range("b2").Value) Then
        MsgBox "Not Feasible"
    Else
        MsgBox "Feasible"
    End If


End Sub
```

Hello at the moment I click a button and the button runs the above macro. It performs the solver function. 
However I want to run for 100 conditions given to me by a drop down list. How can I put the above in a for loop and run the solver 100 times, one after the other. The drop down list is in cell A2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you wanted?

```
For i = 1 to 100

    'Change "MyDropDownList" to your DDL's name
    MyDropDownList.ClearSelection()
    MyDropDownList.Items(i).Selected = True

    Range("F29").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$F$29", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$18:$D$26", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$F$29", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$18:$D$26", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

    'Repeating the scroll in a loop is not a good idea IMO, you should just remove it
    'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12

    If (Range("f29").Value > Range("b2").Value) Then
        MsgBox "Not Feasible"
    Else
        MsgBox "Feasible"
    End If
Next
```